# Getting different output from seemingly identical calculations

Tags: c++, math

Can anyone tell me why the calculations on lines 9 and 11, which seem to be identical, produce two different outputs. I know the difference isn't that great, but I am using these values to draw lines with OpenGL and the difference is noticeable.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

int main()
{
    int ypos=400;

    /// Output: 410.
    std::cout <<  400+(sin((90*3.14159)/180)*10) << std::endl;

    ypos=ypos+(sin((90*3.14159)/180)*10);
    /// Output: 409.
    std::cout << ypos << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *real* answer is somewhere around `409.9999999`.

This is outputting a `double` and rounding to `410` because the math is all inlined:

```
std::cout <<  400+(sin((90*3.14159)/180)*10) << std::endl;
```

since `ypos` is declared as an `int`, the double value is being *truncated* to `409` (which is the defined behavior when casting from `double` to `int`):

```
ypos=ypos+(sin((90*3.14159)/180)*10);

/// Output: 409.
std::cout << ypos << std::endl;
```

Note that you *could* also increase the accuracy by using a better constant for PI:

```
const double PI = 3.141592653589793238463;

std::cout <<  400+(sin((90*PI)/180)*10) << std::endl;
```

but I would still store the result in a `double` instead of an `int` to avoid truncating.  If you *need* an integer result then I would round first:

```
ypos += round(sin((90*PI)/180)*10);
```

Answer (score 6):

This is outputting a floating point number

```
 std::cout <<  400+(sin((90*3.14159)/180)*10) << std::endl;
```

But this is outputting an integer, so will have been truncated

```
std::cout << ypos << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an instance of [GCC's most common non bug](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/#nonbugs)

That's how float behaves. Because of rounding error you don't get an exact result. It is extremely close to 410 for example `409.99999923`. However, if you print it as a float, by default c++ round to 6 figures and thus gives you `410`. In the second time, you assign it to integer. In this case, c++ doesn't perform a **rounding** but a **truncation**. This is why 409.

Answer (score 1):

To keep your code stable so your OpenGL output behaves nicely, you should probably do all (or as much as possible) of your calculations using doubles so that truncation effects do not accumulate and at the end (where I assume you need an integer pixel number) either always round to generate an integer value or truncate, but not mix the two.