# type cast C++ behaves in a strange way

Tags: c++, types, casting

this may be a dumb question but I'm encountering a strange problem.

I found that this line of code

```
cout << long((15.25-14.74)*100) << endl
```

would output 50. Whereas this line

```
cout << long(0.51*100) << endl
```

would output 51.

My question is why they are different and why does the first one output 50 and not 51?

Comment: GCC most common non bug again... Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863568/getting-different-output-from-seemingly-identical-calculations/21863711#21863711

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact.

Comment: if due to floating point imprecision you get 15.25-14.74=0.5099999999 casting it to int by truncation will drop all the 9s.

Comment: It is not "GCC most common non bug". We just have different rounding errors here.

Answer (score 4):

In float-point arithmetics real numbers may sometimes not be what you expect, because precision is finite. In your case `0.51` is actually `0.50999999`.

Comment: I would have thought it was 0.51000001 unless a long cast rounds instead of truncating.

Comment: @cup standard does not dive that deep into implementation, so this solely depends on FPU and/or compiler.